# iOS APNS - Are notifications still sent to devices after app is removed from store

Tags: ios, app-store, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm in the process of transitioning my app to a new developer account, which will mean deleting the app from the store and re-submitting under the new account.  My app uses APNS and my question is will the notifications continue to be sent to existing installed apps after I 'Remove from sale'?  How about after I delete the app entirely?  I'd like to send a message to inform users the app is moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer my own question now - I went ahead and removed the app from the app store, and then completely deleted the app.  I am pleased to say the push notifications are continuing to be delivered OK.